# Get total amount of time between records when changed state

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

I have a table, showing the status (healthy, broken) for each device at a given timestamp. I need to get the total amount of time of a whole breakdown.

So the data is stored like this:

```
device_owner   device_id    timestamp          status
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 09:00   0
owner1         device_2     2001-01-01 09:15   0
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 09:30   1
owner1         device_2     2001-01-01 09:45   1
```

and so on.

The example above shows

- device_1 was down from 09:00 to 09:30 (total 30 mins),
- device_2 was down from 09:15 to 09:45 (total 30 mins)

**What I need**

Need to calculate the total amount of time for the whole breakdown for `owner_1` will be 45 mins (from 09:00 to 09:45) instead of 60 mins (30 + 30).

```
device_owner   total_breakdown_min
owner_1        45
```

**What I've done**

Currently I can define a breakdown time for each device separately (device_1 = 30mins, device_2 = 30mins). For this I transformed the table using `LEAD over partition by device_owner, device_id and date part from timestamp`:

```
device_owner  device_id     timestamp        status lead_timestamp   lead_status
owner1        device_1     2001-01-01 09:00   0     2001-01-01 09:30     1
owner1        device_1     2001-01-01 09:30   1     NULL                 NULL
owner1        device_2     2001-01-01 09:15   0     2001-01-01 09:45     1
owner1        device_2     2001-01-01 09:45   1     NULL                 NULL
```

So the datetime difference between timestamp and lead_timestamp in sum gives me the total breakdown time for a device.

```
;WITH LeadStatus AS
(
    SELECT
        D.*,
        lead_status = LEAD(D.status) OVER (PARTITION BY D.device_owner, D.device_id, D.date ORDER BY D.datetime ASC),
        lead_timestamp = LEAD(D.datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY D.device_owner, D.device_id, D.date ORDER BY D.datetime ASC)
    FROM
        #DeviceStatus AS D
)
SELECT * FROM LeadStatus
```

It is the same device list for any owner. The data snapshot is to be taken between 2 dates (`StartDate`, `EndDate`).
The records are written to a DB each n seconds and also when the device status changes.

Comment: Are you looking for all breakdowns to be combined into a single row, or is each breakdown shown separately? For example, if `device_1` went down again from 11:00 to 11:30 that same day, would `owner1` have one row that said 75 minutes total breakdown, or would he have two rows, one that said 45 minutes and another that said 30 minutes?

Comment: @ScottM, it would be one row with 75 minutes. Unless any other device breaks at 11:00 till 11:45 for example.

Comment: Is it possible to make this kind of calculations with MS SQL?

Comment: Yes it is, I've done something similar before. If I have time later I'll try to work out the details.

Comment: @ScottM, I would really really appreciate, since it's super urgent for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation and an `OVER` clause to get the number of broken devices for each row in `devicestatus`.

```
SELECT device_owner,
       timestamp,
       sum(CASE status
             WHEN 0
               THEN 1
             WHEN 1
               THEN -1
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                      ORDER BY timestamp) broken#
       FROM devicestatus;
```

We now use `lag()` to get the previous number of broken devices for each row.

```
SELECT device_owner,
       timestamp,
       broken#,
       lag(broken#,
           1,
           0) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                    ORDER BY timestamp) previous_broken#
       FROM (SELECT device_owner,
                    timestamp,
                    sum(CASE status
                          WHEN 0
                            THEN 1
                          WHEN 1
                            THEN -1
                        END) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                                   ORDER BY timestamp) broken#
                    FROM devicestatus) x1;
```

Now we use conditional aggregation and the `OVER` clause once again to get an identifier for each period where at least one device of a user was down.

```
SELECT device_owner,
       timestamp,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN previous_broken# = 0
               THEN 1
             ELSE
               0
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                      ORDER BY timestamp) broken_period#
       FROM (SELECT device_owner,
                    timestamp,
                    broken#,
                    lag(broken#,
                        1,
                        0) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                                 ORDER BY timestamp) previous_broken#
                    FROM (SELECT device_owner,
                                 timestamp,
                                 sum(CASE status
                                       WHEN 0
                                         THEN 1
                                       WHEN 1
                                         THEN -1
                                     END) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                                                ORDER BY timestamp) broken#
                                 FROM devicestatus) x1) x2;
```

From here on we can now use `GROUP BY` to get the minimum and maximum timestamp of the periods where at least one device of a user was down.

```
SELECT device_owner,
       max(timestamp) mints,
       min(timestamp) maxts
       FROM (SELECT device_owner,
                    timestamp,
                    sum(CASE
                          WHEN previous_broken# = 0
                            THEN 1
                          ELSE
                            0
                        END) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                                   ORDER BY timestamp) broken_period#
                    FROM (SELECT device_owner,
                                 timestamp,
                                 broken#,
                                 lag(broken#,
                                     1,
                                     0) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                                              ORDER BY timestamp) previous_broken#
                                 FROM (SELECT device_owner,
                                              timestamp,
                                              sum(CASE status
                                                    WHEN 0
                                                      THEN 1
                                                    WHEN 1
                                                      THEN -1
                                                  END) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                                                             ORDER BY timestamp) broken#
                                              FROM devicestatus) x1) x2) x3
       GROUP BY device_owner,
                broken_period#;
```

We can now simply use `datediff()`, `sum()` and `GROUP BY` to calculate the total downtime for each device owner.

```
SELECT device_owner,
       sum(datediff(minute,
                    maxts,
                    mints)) total_breakdown_min
       FROM (SELECT device_owner,
                    max(timestamp) mints,
                    min(timestamp) maxts
                    FROM (SELECT device_owner,
                                 timestamp,
                                 sum(CASE
                                       WHEN previous_broken# = 0
                                         THEN 1
                                       ELSE
                                         0
                                     END) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                                                ORDER BY timestamp) broken_period#
                                 FROM (SELECT device_owner,
                                              timestamp,
                                              broken#,
                                              lag(broken#,
                                                  1,
                                                  0) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                                                           ORDER BY timestamp) previous_broken#
                                              FROM (SELECT device_owner,
                                                           timestamp,
                                                           sum(CASE status
                                                                 WHEN 0
                                                                   THEN 1
                                                                 WHEN 1
                                                                   THEN -1
                                                               END) OVER (PARTITION BY device_owner
                                                                          ORDER BY timestamp) broken#
                                                           FROM devicestatus) x1) x2) x3
                    GROUP BY device_owner,
                             broken_period#) x4
       GROUP BY device_owner;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a4840/1)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, works like a charm except the case when the day starts with a device already working, you can check by adding any working device at the top

Comment: @GyuzalR: Still works for me: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8f62f/1). Note `'owner7'` with `'device_7'` at 07:07. It gets 0 minutes for `'owner_7'`. But you can add `HAVING sum(datediff(minute, maxts, mints)) <> 0` if you want to exclude results with 0 minutes;

Comment: ok, solved this by removing extra data. What about leading 0 status? Used the same fiddle but with repeated zero statuses at 09:01 and 09:02 [link here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/42bc9/1)

Answer (score 1):

My idea behind it , is to find the next active record ( with status  = 1) that is greater in timestamp then current record . For this I used `OUTER APPLY`

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([device_owner] varchar(6), [device_id] varchar(8), [timestamp] datetime, [status] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([device_owner], [device_id], [timestamp], [status])
VALUES
    ('owner1', 'device_1', '2001-01-01 09:00:00', 0),
    ('owner1', 'device_2', '2001-01-01 09:15:00', 0),
    ('owner1', 'device_1', '2001-01-01 09:30:00', 1),
    ('owner1', 'device_2', '2001-01-01 09:45:00', 1),
    ('owner1', 'device_3', '2001-01-01 11:00:00', 0),
    ('owner1', 'device_3', '2001-01-01 11:30:00', 1)
;
```

-- logic it's inside CTE

```
;WITH myCTE
AS
(
SELECT 
    [device_owner] , [device_id] , [timestamp] , [status] 
    ,CASE WHEN T.status  = 0 THEN OA.next_ts_active ELSE NULL END as next_ts_active
FROM Table1 AS T
   OUTER APPLY  /* give me the next active position*/
   (SELECT TOP(1) timestamp as next_ts_active
    FROM Table1 as OT
    WHERE T.device_owner = OT.device_owner
         AND OT.Status = 1
         AND T.timestamp < OT.timestamp
    ORDER BY OT.timestamp ASC
   )OA -- for active
)
SELECT device_owner
    ,SUM(case when status = 0 
          then datediff(minute,timestamp,next_ts_active) 
          else 0 end) as diff_minutes
FROM myCTE
GROUP BY device_owner
```

Output- only the CTE

```
device_owner    device_id   timestamp           status  next_ts_active
owner1          device_1    01/01/2001 09:00:00 0       01/01/2001 09:30:00
owner1          device_2    01/01/2001 09:15:00 0       01/01/2001 09:30:00
owner1          device_1    01/01/2001 09:30:00 1       null
owner1          device_2    01/01/2001 09:45:00 1       null
owner1          device_3    01/01/2001 11:00:00 0       01/01/2001 11:30:00
owner1          device_3    01/01/2001 11:30:00 1       null
```

Then apply the difference and sum it :

```
device_owner    diff_minutes
owner1          75
```

It's 75 because I added a new device :device_3. Without it, value it's 45 . See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7aa8a5e1ce55642750844e47320a3198)